# How to aggregate mapping table?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

I don't know how to put my questions into words, so I couldn't search for it specifically. I searched for some time but could not find a solution that fits my problem. I know I could create a custom solution by iterating over all the rows multiple times, but I'm hoping there is a more efficient way to solve the problem. Here is the dataframe I have:

```
id_old  id_new
A1      A2
A2      A3
A4      A5
```

This is a mapping table and I want to change the first row because the ID has been updated again.

I look for this result:

```
id_old  id_new
A1      A3
A2      A3
A4      A5
```

Any help is welcome :-)

Best

Comment: if you are looking to change the value, you can do, df.loc['id_old'=='A1'] = 'A3'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

Try via `mask()` and `bfill()`:

```
df['id_new']=df['id_new'].mask(df['id_new'].isin(df['id_old'])).bfill()
```

**Explaination:**

Checking If values of 'id_new' is in 'id_old' via `isin()`

So `isin()` method is giving us a boolean series so we are passing that series to `mask()` method so basically where where condition matches `mask()` method put `NaN` since we are chaining it on 'id_new' column so it will give `NaN` where the value in mask is True and where it is False it will give the values of 'id_new' column

Finally backword filling values via `bfill()` method

Answer (score 0):

Your dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"id_old": ["A1", "A2", "A4"], "id_new": ["A2", "A3", "A5"]})
```

If you need to modify only the first row, you could just assign it directly:

```
#(0: first row, 1: second column):
df.iat[0, 1] = "A3"
```

Alternatively, you could look by name:

```
df.loc[df["id_old"] == "A1", "id_new"] = "A3"
```

Or using a list of old IDs and another list for the new values*:

```
old_id = ["A1", "A4"]
new_values = ["A3", "A7"]

selection = df["id_old"].isin(old_id)

df.loc[selection, "id_new"] = new_values
```

*I modified in this example also the value of A4, just to have more than one value in the list.